# I want to call data from other table by clicking the link

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-server

**Category Table**

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (
>     contents varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>     id smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     PRIMARY KEY (id)
>
> INSERT INTO category (contents, id) VALUES
>   ('food', 1),
>   ('electronics', 2),
>   ('grocery', 3);

**Content details Table**

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS content_details (
>     cd_id smallint(6) NOT NULL,
>     contents varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>     details text NOT NULL,
>     id smallint(6) NOT NULL,
>     KEY link_id (id)
>
> INSERT INTO content_details (cd_id, contents, details, id) VALUES
>   (1, 'food', 'Food is any substance consumed..', 1),
>   (2, 'electronics', 'Electronics is the science..', 2),
>   (3, 'grocery', 'A grocery store is a retail store....', 3);

When i open my main file *index.php* it must show contents from category table in link form like :

```
Id     contents
1      Food 
2      Electronics 
3      Grocery
```

Now my question is that when i click on "food" link  it should open "**details**" from content_details table and show them on new file i.e. **view.php** here is my code for index.php:

```
<?php
//Open a new connection to the MySQL server <br>
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','article_management'); <br>

//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) { 
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
} 

//MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, contents FROM category");

print '<table border="1">'; 
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $id = $row['id'];
    $contents = $row['contents'];
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$row["id"].'</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="view.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $contents . '</a></td>';
    print '</tr>'; 
}  
print '</table>';

// Frees the memory associated with a result <br>
$results->free();

// close connection 
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

So, i want the new page should display the "details" content respective to the link open.
For example when i click on food it should open food description from content_details table. For grocery it should open grocery details and so on

Code for my **view.php** which I have written is given below. Its not working I don't know where i am wrong:

```
<?PHP 
$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT details, id 
FROM content_details 
WHERE id = $id");


echo "<table width=100%>
<tr>
<th>Content Details</th>
<th>Numbers</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> <a href='#'>" . $row['details'] . "</a> </td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] .  "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: pass the id in query string and get the value $_GET and fetch the details from database on the page using $_GET['id'];

Comment: create relationship for both table

Comment: can anyone give me the code please.

Comment: same thing how you showing list of category same way you try with where id =$_GET['id'];

Comment: Table name is content_details or details?

Comment: sorry @MikhailMalov my bad table name is "content_details" and column name is "details"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View.php

```
<?php
//Open a new connection to the MySQL server <br>
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','article_management'); <br>

//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) { 
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
} 

$category_id = (int)$_GET['id'];

//MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT details FROM content_details where id = $category_id");

print '<table border="1">'; 
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $details = $row['details'];
    print '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $details . '</td>';
    print '</tr>'; 
}  
print '</table>';

// Frees the memory associated with a result <br>
$results->free();

// close connection 
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Please give me table name and structure (for details)

Comment: table names are table1 - "category",   table 2 - "content_details" table 1 has "id, contents"  table 2 has "cd_id, contents, details, id"

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Sorry, I was doing some mistake but later on i figured out. Thanks a lot @mikhail

Comment: echo '<td><a href="view.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $contents . '</a></td>'; how can i put this in html code ?

Answer (score 0):

Code for your **view.php** should be like this, as per your table structure:

```
    <?PHP 
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $con=mysqli_connect("hostname","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT content_details, id 
    FROM content_details WHERE id = $id");


    echo "<table width=100%>
    <tr>
    <th>Content Details</th>
    <th>Numbers</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> <a href='#'>" . $row['details'] . "</a> </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] .  "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    ?>
```